# XAMPP & MySQL - both need to be installed to run SQL in terminal?

Tags: mysql, xampp

I've installed XAMPP in my Ubuntu, but when I try to run MySQL in terminal, error comes as MySQL is not installed. Since I installed XAMPP, MySQL should also be installed right?

Comment: Yes. It's the M in XAMPP

Comment: As i see from xampp download page - `XAMPP is an easy to install Apache distribution containing MariaDB, PHP, and Perl.`. MariaDB not MySQL

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Xampp allows you to use Mysql through PhpMyAdmin user interface.
For Mysql in termal go through the below link
[Install Mysql](https://askubuntu.com/questions/174138/how-to-install-mysql)